# how to define editor.selectionBackground in Visual Studio Code based on theme?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

in my settings.json I have the following.

```
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editor.selectionBackground": "#EBFF38",  //light theme
    "editor.selectionHighlightBackground": "#AEFF95",  //light theme
    //"editorBracketMatch.background": "#ff0000",  //dark theme
    //"editorBracketMatch.border": "#ff00ff",      //dark theme
  },
```

every night I need to comment the first 2 lines at the top

every morning I need to comment the first 2 lines at the bottom

is there any way to do this automatically? when selecting the theme ?

please advise, thank you

Comment: have two version of vs code say (main version and insider version). Use main version in day time and insider version in night time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "[your light theme name]": {
       "editor.selectionBackground": "#EBFF38",  //light theme
       "editor.selectionHighlightBackground": "#AEFF95",  //light theme
    },
    "[your dark theme name]": {
       "editorBracketMatch.background": "#ff0000",  //dark theme
       "editorBracketMatch.border": "#ff00ff",      //dark theme
    },
    [rest of your colorCustomizations]
}
```

See [vscode docs: customizing a color theme](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes#_customizing-a-color-theme).